# How to define offsetof() macro in GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I want to define some auxiliary marcos in GDB for convenience, one of them is the `offsetof()` macro.

I tried

```
define offsetof
    if $argc == 2
        (int)(&((($arg0 *)0)->$arg1))
    end
end
```

It doesn't work because:

1. A type such as `struct node` will be splitted into `Struct` and `node`, so `$arg0 = Struct`, `$arg1 = node`.
2. I am not sure if gdb's command can return a value.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Rather than define `offsetof` as a command, I think it's better to define it as a function.  That way you can use it in expressions; and if you just want to see the offset you can always just use `print`.

There are two ways to define `offsetof` as a function.

If you are debugging C or C++, you can simply define it as a macro:

```
(gdb) macro define offsetof(t, f) &((t *) 0)->f
```

So given:

```
struct x {
  int a;
  long b;
};
```

On my machine I get:

```
(gdb) p offsetof(struct x, a)
$1 = (int *) 0x0
(gdb) p offsetof(struct x, b)
$2 = (long *) 0x8
```

The reason for the "C or C++" restriction above is that other languages don't run their expressions through gdb's built-in preprocessor.

If you want it to work in other languages, then the answer is to write a new convenience function in Python.  This is a bit more involved, but see the gdb documentation for `gdb.Function`.

Comment: What you wrote returns a pointer but the original macro returns an integer.  That can break the expressions people use, but fortunately it's easy to fix that, e.g.
`macro define offsetof(t, f) (size_t)&((t *) 0)->f`

Answer (score 1):

If you use python to define `offsetof`, you might begin with something like this:

```
import gdb

class offsetof(gdb.Command):

    def invoke(self, args, from_tty):
        value, name = args.split()
        struct = gdb.parse_and_eval(value)
        fields = { field.name: field for field in struct.type.fields() }   
        gdb.write("{} offset: {} bits\n".format(name, fields[name].bitpos))

offsetof("offsetof", gdb.COMMAND_USER)
```

If you save that to a file, and insure that the directory where you save it is in `sys.path`, you can import it. For example, if you save it to your home directory, you might do something along these lines:

```
(gdb) pi
>>> import os
>>> sys.path.insert(0, os.getenv('HOME'))
>>> import offsetof
>>>
(gdb)
```

If your gdb has no `pi` command you can prepend `python` to each command following a `>>>` prompt.

If gdb imports `offsetof` with no complaint, you should then be able to invoke `offsetof` as a gdb command. As written it expects two arguments (space separated), a value, and a name. If the value is a struct with a field having the provided name, it will report the offset in bits (not bytes, because the underlying python code can handle bitfields).

The code here can be improved. It has no real error handling beyond what it inherits from the code it calls, and as written it doesn't handle pointers.

[This page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html) describes some of the underlying code used in that example; the `target` method it mentions might provide the beginnings of handling pointers (or you can just dereference pointers in the values you pass in, i.e. you might specify `*this` rather than `this` as the first parameter). The section on `Type.fields()` mentions other attributes besides `bitpos` which might also be of interest if you want to report other details about struct layout.